# openGL glGenList Segmentation Fault on OSX

Tags: macos, opengl, glut

I am working with OpenGL and am having an issue using glGenLists. Every time I call it, I am getting a segfault. I wrote a simple program to test if it was the external libraries I was using, but discovered it was not. Here is the simple program:

```
#include "GLUT/glut.h"

int main(){
    GLuint list = glGenLists(1);
    return 0;
}
```

I am running this on Mac OS X 10.6.7 and am compile with:

```
g++ -framework OpenGL -framework GLUT -o test test.cpp
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 7):

I believe, before using any OpenGL commands, you have to set up your OpenGL context.

There are a few things you have to do before you can just jump in and draw some triangles. You have to let the OS know that you need a window of x size with y properties, and that you're going to be drawing in it with OpenGL.

If you don't know how to set up your OpenGL context, you could try [this](http://nehe.gamedev.net/data/lessons/lesson.asp?lesson=Mac_OS). It could be old and a bit deprecated, but it'll work :)

Comment: that did the trick. I didn't even notice that when doing it in my actual project. THANKS! :D

Comment: The link is dead, but I'm having the same problems. Do you remember what the issue was?